# Making a lazy, cached observable that only execute the source once

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to use an rxjs observable to delegate, but share, a piece of expensive work across the lifetime of an application.

Essentially, something like:

```
var work$ = Observable.create((o) => {
  const expensive = doSomethingExpensive();
  o.next(expensive);
  observer.complete();
})
.publishReplay(1)
.refCount();
```

Now, this works fine and does exactly what I want, except for one thing: if all subscribers unsubscribe, then when the next one subscribes, my expensive work happens again. I want to keep it.

now, I could use a subject, or I could remove the refCount() and use connect manually (and never disconnect). But that would make the expensive work happen the moment I connect, not the first time a subscriber tries to consume work$.

Essentially, I want something akin to refCount that only looks at the first subscription to connect, and never disconnect. A "lazy connect".

Is such a thing possible at all?

Comment: Does it work to simply create the as a startWith() then chain a mapping operation to it (using the identity function) and let the consumers subscribe to the mapped output Observable instead of the actual source?

Comment: This is documented behaviour, at least. It's kinda direty, but maybe you can add one subscriber that will basically make the observable keep a refcount of 1 or more, so it doesn't flush the cached piece of work. I went through the API, but I can't find another way to keep the cache without subscribers.

Comment: So, I played with it a bit more, and this is not doing what I'd expect (but it is doing what I want!).

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phoenixmatrix/metrezfd/)

I'm not sure I understand. I would have expected refCount and the publishReplay operation to happen again (and to create a new connectable observable) from the source data every time subscribers hit 0. But this isn't happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How does [`publishReplay()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/publishReplay.ts) actually work

It internally creates a [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/ReplaySubject.ts) and makes it `multicast` compatible. The minimal replay value of `ReplaySubject` is 1 emission. This results in the following:

- First subscription will trigger the `publishReplay(1)` to internally subscribe to the source stream and pipe all emissions through the `ReplaySubject`, effectively caching the last *n*(=1) emissions
- If a second subscription is started while the source is still active the `multicast()` will connect us to the same `replaySubject` and we will receive all next emissions until the source stream completes.
- If a subscription is started after the source is already completed the replaySubject has cached the last *n* emissions and it will only receive those before completing.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1,2])
  .mergeMap(i => Rx.Observable.of('emission:'+i).delay(i * 100))
  .do(null,null,() => console.log('source stream completed'))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();

// two subscriptions which are both in time before the stream completes
source.subscribe(val => console.log(`sub1:${val}`), null, () => console.log('sub1 completed'));
source.subscribe(val => console.log(`sub2:${val}`), null, () => console.log('sub2 completed'));

// new subscription after the stream has completed already
setTimeout(() => {
  source.subscribe(val => console.log(`sub_late-to-the-party:${val}`), null, () => console.log('sub_late-to-the-party completed'));
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```